# Flatten an array of objects to an array of one object by reduce

Tags: javascript

I want to convert:

```
[ { foo: 'media' }, { article: 'article' } ]
```

to:

```
[{foo: 'media', article: 'article'}]
```

I tried :

```
var newdata=[ { foo: 'media' }, { article: 'article' } ].reduce(function(p, c, i, array) {   
  return p[Object.keys(c)[0]]=c[Object.keys(c)[0]]
}, {});
```

but it returns "article" am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Reduce expects you to return the partical result back in order to iterate over following items. Therefore the following code would work:

```
var newdata=[ { foo: 'media' }, { article: 'article' } ].reduce(function(p, c, i, array) {   
  // Add item to the array
  p[Object.keys(c)[0]]=c[Object.keys(c)[0]];
  // And return back the object to reduce into
  return p;
}, {});
```

which outputs:

```
> newdata
Object {foo: "media", article: "article"}
```

Comment: *"Reduce expects you to return the array back in order to iterate over following items."* Reduce doesn't expect anything though. It entirely depends on what you are using reduce for.

Comment: I think you want to say in your code comment that it will return object and not array. :)

Comment: What reduce expects you to return is the partial result from that step of the reduction.

Answer (score 0):

> am I doing something wrong

Most likely, since you are not getting the result you want.

An assignment expression results in the value that was assigned:

```
foo = 'bar';
// returns 'bar';
```

Now, the return value of the callback becomes the input for the next iteration of the callback. But you don't want to pass the assigned value to the next iteration of `reduce` though, because that would result in the following reduction:

```
// 1. iteration
p = {}, c = { foo: 'media' }

// 2. iteration
p = 'media', c = { article: 'article' }

// result
'article'
```

Instead, you want:

```
// 1. iteration
p = {}, c = { foo: 'media' }

// 2. iteration
p = { foo: 'media' }, c = { article: 'article' }

// result
{ foo: 'media', article: 'article' }
```

In order to achieve that, you have to return `p` from the callback, so that in every iteration, the property and its value can be added to it.

You could leverage the comma operator to get a one-liner:

```
return (p[Object.keys(c)[0]] = c[Object.keys(c)[0]]), p;
//                                                  ^^^
```

This will assign the property and return `p`. But better would be

```
var key = Object.keys(c)[0];
p[key] = c[key];
return p;
```